# Silverlight - Showing a png in image control from a file on local harddrive

Tags: silverlight, image, controls

I am struggling to show a picture in a silverlight image control.

The file is situated locally on my hard-drive.

Is it possible to load an image from hard-drive into a silverlight image control?

Everything I have searched so far doesn't seem to relate to loading from hard-drive.

Do I need to first save it as a resource?

I am currently doing something like this:

```
Image pic = new Image();

Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\Briefcase\PDF.bmp", UriKind.Relative);

pic.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uri);

canvas.Children.Add(pic);
pic.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToDouble(100));
pic.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToDouble(100));
pic.Height = 70;
pic.Width = 600;
```

Is my Uri correct? because I have also tried:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("C:/Briefcase/PDF.bmp", UriKind.Relative);
```

Does it perhaps have something to do with silverlight not having access to my local drive? If so How would I go about loading an image into the control dynamically?

Many thanks.

Neill

**UPDATE:**

Solved my problem by loading the image into the image control directly from MemoryStream

```
byte[] logo = e.Result;

logoStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(logo);

System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage b = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
b.SetSource(logoStream);
ownerLogo.Source = b;
```

regards

Neill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight restricts your access to a small set of locations in the default mode. You can actually access files in other locations on the computer if you set your application to run OOB and with elevated trust (in fact, I think with SL5 you don't even need OOB), but that may or may not be a good solution for your application.

If you're just trying to use an icon and plan to distribute it with your application, then you should definitely add it to the project as a resource though.

Comment: What I am trying to do is read an image from sql and show that as a logo. I can retrieve the image from the database no problem, so what would then be the easiest way to display it? can i do it straight from the MemoryStream? Or if not, can I programmatically add it as a resource?

Comment: See updated for answer - thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons,  Silverlight does not let you access files on a users local machine outside of Isolated Storage or through File open/save dialogs (and these must be through user initiated actions).

With a elevated trust Silverlight 4 application, you can access My Documents, My Pictures, My Videos, and My Music folders directly.  To make an application full-trust in SL4, it must be out of browser.  Is this what you want?   (SL 5 allows full file system access out of browser, and has in-browswer elevated permissions available as well, but that requires a registry change.)

Comment: No problem.  For the future, you can also answer your own question instead of editing the question.